# Inherit color from color property into background-color property while using a different color in color property

Tags: html, css

I want to inherit color from color property into background-color property while using a different color in color property

```
<style>
.parentClass{
  color:"red"
}
.myclass {
   color: "blue";
   background-color: {{ Inherit parent's color property value }}
}
</style>
<div class="parentClass">
   <div class="myclass"> sometext </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Kindly share your html code as well, it will help to understand the structure, and will give more idea about the requirement.

Comment: added html code as well.